# Want to change Xcode Project from iOS 6.1 to iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

i created an iPhone app in Xcode 4.6.1 which supports only up to iOS 6.1. i want to run the app in iOS 7. is that possible? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 6 apps run on iOS 7 devices. If you want to "convert" just launch the app in xcode 5 and it will ask if you want to migrate to iOS 7, say yes to do so. If you do, you won't be able to take the app back to iOS 6 and xcode 4.

Personally I haven't launched on xcode 5 because there are bugs with it and crashes often

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is definitely possible.

When you open your `Storyboard` or `.XIB` file, Xcode 5 will prompt you if you want to upgrade your `User Interface` to iOS 7 style. You can choose to ignore that. And your app will run as is on the iOS Simulator.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just tick this answer to tell people that it solved your problem. And upvote also ;)

Answer (score 0):

New operating systems (iOS 7) are written as to add new features, while still running programs written in older operating systems, provided the old operating systems are not VERY old, or problems might happen. An iPhone with iOS 7 will run the iOS 6 program, while an iOS 6 phone would not run a program written for iOS 7. You say you wrote the program to support "up to iOS  6.1" - that is probably not precise. Your program supports from 6.1 UPWARDS ;). A phone with iOS 5 would not run your program. In other words, when you set your support to 6.1, it doesn't mean your code will be supported by all iOS's up to 6.1, but that your code can only be supported by 6.1 and up.